# android create shortcut application view in the view

Tags: android

I want to create in my application, shortcut application view view in the view its something look like clonal of the quick contact badge but with my own custom  application icon 
  the picture  below  appear in this picture  after click in button

[image]

this  is the code  of "quick contact badge "

```
                    Uri contactUri = data.getData();  
                FrameLayout badgeLargeHolder = (FrameLayout)  
                       findViewById(R.id.badge_holder_large);  

                QuickContactBadge badgeLarge = new QuickContactBadge(this);  
                badgeLarge.assignContactUri(contactUri);  
                badgeLarge.setMode(ContactsContract.QuickContact.MODE_LARGE);  
                badgeLarge.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);  
                badgeLargeHolder.addView(badgeLarge);
```

How i can modify it  to make it similar to what i want to do
so any help and before all what is the specific name of this view ?

Answer (score 0):

i find what im looking for , its call Quick action
http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/quick-actions